# Optimizing azure virtual machine size

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have a web app hosted on Ubuntu-based Azure classic virtual machine (size DS14). The CPU usage, load, memory, disk I/O and network I/O changes over the previous 7 days are as follows:

[image]

Clearly, there's opportunity to save money here by scaling my infrastructure dynamically up and down alongwith changes in load, instead of having a DS14 instance running all the time.

Can someone please outline the steps I'll need to do to enable this? My VM is not part of any availability set as of now.

Comment: well, you shut it down and change the size, no other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a classic VM to an availability set. Please refer to this link:[Add an existing virtual machine to an availability set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/configure-availability#a-idaddmachine-aoption-2-add-an-existing-virtual-machine-to-an-availability-set).

Notes: ARM VM does not support add an existing VMs to an availability set.

If you want to VM supports dynamically auto scale, you need at least two VMs in a same availability set. You could refer to this link:[Automatic scale - CPU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale#automatic-scale---cpu).

According to your description, you want to your VM auto up and down, I think it is not possible. When VM is up and down, the VM needs restart, your service will be interrupted for a minutes. As a production environment, this is not acceptable.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you. So I understand what you're saying. I cant increase the *size* automatically, but I can add or remove instances to scale, correct? And that's what's going to save me money.

Comment: Lol, and now the downvoter has gone after my question.

Comment: Yes, you could auto add or remove instances to scale.  You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.